# Mapping different keys to the same value in c++

Tags: c++

So I searched around and found that we can use multi-map to map a set of equivalent keys to different values. I am wondering how to do the reverse? That is to map different keys to the same value? Is there a stl data structure for that?

Comment: A `map` doesn't require that values be unique. Just keys.

Comment: Just invert the map so the values are the keys and vice-versa

Answer (score 7):

A normal `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) can do that. You have a few choices on how to do that:

- Normal key-value store, where you copy the values as needed
- Normal key-value store, but where the value is a pointer to the actual data that can be shared, optionally using a `std::shared_ptr`
- Use some kind of structure (a `std::tuple` perhaps) to collect the keys (though it's probably more trouble handling this than it's worth, nothing I really recommend)
- Use [Boost multi-index containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

With Boost you have a ready solution that you can just use, and if you already use Boost in your project (it is a great set of libraries, and complements the standard library well) I think it's a no-brainer to pick that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `std::map` such that multiple keys map to the same value. There is nothing against that. However, what you are probably looking for is the ability to to find all the keys that map to a given value without iterating over the entire map. I don't think there is any such data structure for that.

Comment: @Sahu Yea actually I created a map that looks like this: std::map<std::pair<std::string,std::tuple<int,int,int>>,std::string> m. The problem is that when I give a pair entry that exists to this map m, it prints out nothing for the value. What could be wrong here? I thought maybe because there are duplicate values, and the map only allows one-to-one correspondence. That's the reason I posted this. Any help would be thankful.

Comment: @dl23lin, in that case, you should delete this question and ask another question with the code you have tried, what you expected to see, what are actually seeing. That will be more useful than this question.